# @Input property is undefined

Tags: angular

I have 2 components one of them sets input property of another component.
The problem is that the input property is undefined at time of use.
First component:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Comparison} from "../../../common/domain/comparison";
@Component({
    selector: 'oe-comparison-list',
        template: `<div class="row" *ngFor="let comparisons of comparisonRows">
    <oe-comparison-thumbnail *ngFor="let comparison of comparisons" [comparison]="comparison"></oe-comparison-thumbnail>
</div>`,
    styleUrls: ['./comparison-list.component.css']
})
export class ComparisonListComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input("comparisons")
    private comparisons: Array<Comparison>;
    private comparisonRows: Array<Array<Comparison>>;
    private static readonly COLUMNS: number = 4;

    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.rows();
    }

    private rows(): void {
        //todo
        this.comparisonRows = [];
        let comparisonArray = [];
        for (let i: number = 0; i < this.comparisons.length; ++i) {
            if (i == 0 || i % ComparisonListComponent.COLUMNS != 0) {
                comparisonArray.push(this.comparisons[i]);
            } else {
                this.comparisonRows.push(comparisonArray);
                comparisonArray = [];
            }
        }
        if (this.comparisons.length < ComparisonListComponent.COLUMNS) {
            this.comparisonRows.push(comparisonArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Second component

```
import {AfterViewChecked, Component, Inject, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Comparison} from "../../../common/domain/comparison";
import {IComparisonService} from "../../../common/services/icomparison.service";
@Component({
    selector: 'oe-comparisons-view',
    template: `<oe-comparison-list [comparisons]="comparisons"></oe-comparison-list>`,
    styleUrls: ['./comparisons-view.component.css']
})
export class ComparisonsViewComponent implements AfterViewChecked, OnInit {

    private comparisons: Array<Comparison>;

    constructor(@Inject('IComparisonService') private comparisonService: IComparisonService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.comparisonService.fetchComparisons()
            .then(comparisons => this.comparisons = comparisons);
    }
    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    }
}
```

If i pass simple array from ngOnInit() from second component without promise everything works just fine.
How can i resolve this problem?

ADDED
Service implementation

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Comparison} from "../../../domain/comparison";
import {IComparisonService} from "../../icomparison.service";

@Injectable()
export class ComparisonServiceMock implements IComparisonService {

    private selectedComparison: Comparison;

    constructor() {
    }


    fetchComparisons(): Promise<Array<Comparison>> {
        let comparison: Array<Comparison> = [
            new Comparison(0, "Toys", "Toys comparison description", new Date(), "toys"),
            new Comparison(1, "Tablets", "Tablets comparison description", new Date(), "tablets"),
            new Comparison(2, "Jogurts", "Jogurts comparison description", new Date(), "jogurts"),
        ];
        return Promise.resolve(comparison);
    }

    selectComparison(comparison: Comparison): void {
        this.selectedComparison = comparison;
    }

    getSelectedComparison(): Comparison {
        return this.selectedComparison;
    }

}
```

Comment: did you set your service as a provider in your app.module.ts?

Comment: yes, i get the value from promise (checked it using debug).

Comment: can you add the error you are getting?

Comment: try initializing your array to a empty array. change `private comparisons: Array<Comparison>` to `private comparisons: Comparison[] = []`

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at ComparisonListComponent.webpackJsonp.190.ComparisonListComponent.rows (comparison-list.component.ts:28)`

Comment: I'm guessing that you are able to retrieve data from your service, if so. I think when the `ngOnInit()` fires in the child component, the parent component comparisons is not set yet. Move your `onOnInit()` code in `ComparisonListComponent` into `ngOnChanges()`. And give it a go.

Comment: The same error.

Comment: can you share your `ComparisonService.fetchComarisons()` implementation, I am wondering if you are handling your asynchronous programming via Promises.

Comment: I have updated the main question.

Comment: Try replacing `ngOnInit` to `ngOnChanges` in `ComparisonListComponent `

Comment: Already tried, did not help.

Comment: You should add check if `comparison` is not empty in `ngOnChanges` because first time it will be empty https://plnkr.co/edit/eWKcK5pvsEOfjD4mcL8E?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following changes in your second component

```
import {AfterViewChecked, Component, Inject, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import {Comparison} from "../../../common/domain/comparison";
import {IComparisonService} from "../../../common/services/icomparison.service";
@Component({
    selector: 'oe-comparisons-view',
    template: `<oe-comparison-list [comparisons]="comparisons" *ngIf="!isLoading"></oe-comparison-list>`,
    styleUrls: ['./comparisons-view.component.css']
})
export class ComparisonsViewComponent implements AfterViewChecked, OnInit {

    private comparisons: Array<Comparison>;
    private isLoading: boolean = true;

    constructor(@Inject('IComparisonService') private comparisonService: IComparisonService) {

    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.comparisonService.fetchComparisons()
            .then(comparisons => {
              this.comparisons = comparisons;
              this.isLoading = false;
            });
    }
    ngAfterViewChecked(): void {
    }
}
```

You can read this [3 Ways to Pass Async Data to Angular 2+ Child Components](https://scotch.io/tutorials/3-ways-to-pass-async-data-to-angular-2-child-components) to know more about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a problem with your input variable declaration, try changing:

```
@Input("comparisons")
private comparisons: Array<Comparison>;
```

to

```
@Input("comparisons") comparisons: Array<Comparison>;
```

*or, equivalently*

```
@Input() comparisons: Array<Comparison>;
```

**Update**
You may also need to set the `comparisons` property in `ComparisonsViewComponent` to `public`.

Recent Angular versions dont support accessing `private` members in template code. See https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5620

Comment: It did not help.

Comment: No luck. 
As i mentioned in main question everything worked fine until i added a promise, with a simple array assigned to this.comparisons at ngOnInit() of ComparisonsViewComponent everything worked perfectly.

Comment: Very odd. My only other guess is that its not actually using the mock service you've created. Could you include the module definition where you are providing `ComparisonServiceMock` ?